# android change first blank to "AA"

Tags: java

change first blank to "AA"

```
String a = "a b c";
```

change to

```
String a = "aAAb c";
```

The answer is clear

```
a = a.replaceFirst(" ", "AA");
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Android? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code,you may got the expected answer,

```
String str="a b c";
    boolean a1 = true ; 
    StringBuilder strbu = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0 ; i<str.length();i++)
    {   
        Character b = str.charAt(i);
        if(b.equals(' ') && a1 == true )
        {
            a1 = false;
            strbu = strbu.append("AA");
        }
        else
        {
            strbu = strbu.append(b);
        }
    }
    Log.e("str","string:"+strbu.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.replaceFirst(" ", "AA");`

If you've further problems, do let me know.

Comment: Only you know what I mean.

Comment: TBH, I don't know what you mean